# is it possible to debug javascript code with XCode 4?

Tags: javascript, xcode4

I want to run the simulator and when it is running, debug my javascript code that is launching the pages. I did not find any way to debug javascript code using xcode. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Not as is.

However, Dashcode is meant for this sort of thing. Additionally you can use Safari's rather good developer tools. Open Safari's preferences, click the Advanced tab, and at the bottom, check the "Show Develop menu in menu bar". Explore and go nuts.

Alternatively, you could install [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/) but I believe it only helps you with Objective-J.